Laravel, extract images from excel file and save it in disc
Laravel v10.47.0
PHP v8.2.13
currently using maatwebsite/excel
A user will upload an excel file via webform that will contain information to be inserted in a table in a database. Contains 5 columns: code, concept, price, quantity, photo (optional). Each row is a record (including the photo)
I have no problems to get the first 4 columns, but the photo part I need to extract the image and save in disc to be used later.
Currently I have this code:
$sheets = Excel::toArray(new RecordImport, $tempPathOfExcelFile);
foreach ($sheets as $sheet) {
    foreach ($sheet as $idx => $row) {
        // validation and insert record
    }
}

How I can "read" the image on each row (if it have one) and save it in disk?

Unfortunately Drawings (images) do not exist in a cell, they exist on the Sheet, so getting an image from a row is a bit tricky.
I think laravel-excel delegates its method calls to PhpSreadsheet's Worksheet class, so this should work somewhat.
The PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet\Drawing exposes a getCoordinates method that should return a Cell Coordinate ("À2", for example)
$sheets = Excel::toArray(new RecordImport, $tempPathOfExcelFile);
foreach ($sheets as $sheet) {
    // get an array instead of an ArrayObject so we can use array_filter on it.
    $drawings = $sheet->getDrawingCollection()->getArrayCopy(); 

    foreach ($sheet as $idx => $row) {
        // Assuming photo is in the fifth column (E)
        $filtered = array_filter(
            $drawings,
            fn ($d) => $d->getCoordinates() === "E{$row}"
        );

        $drawing = array_shift($filtered);

        if ($drawing !== null) {
           // follow the PhpSpreadsheet documentation linked below from here.
        }
    }

}


https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/recipes/#reading-images-from-a-worksheet

